# Website floating content containers issue

Tags: html, css

I am building a template just to practice my skills but I have huge issue with floating columns side by side. ( div with name: .sidebar and .content ) I want both of them to be floated left and sitting side by side. Here I will provide my code until this moment. Any suggestions ?

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "myriadpro";
    src: url("../fonts/myriad-pro-bold-condensed-webfont.eot");
    src: url("../fonts/myriad-pro-bold-condensed-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
         url("../fonts/myriad-pro-bold-condensed-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"),
         url("../fonts/myriad-pro-bold-condensed-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
         url("../fonts/myriad-pro-bold-condensed-webfont.svg#myriadpro") format("svg");
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: bold;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: "myriadpro_regular";
 src: url("../fonts/myriadproregular.eot");
 src: local("myriadproregular"), url("../fonts/myriadproregular.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/myriadproregular.ttf") format("truetype");
 font-weight: 300;
 font-style: normal;
}

* { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; outline: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

body, html { height: 100%; }
body {
 font-family: "Bentham", serif, "Arial", sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 1.667;
 background: #f1f1f1;
 color: #3f3f3f;
}

/* Main Template Settings */

.container { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; }
.header { margin-top: 8px; }
.main { background: #fff; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
.sidebar { display: block; width: 206px;  padding: 6px 14px 0 6px; }  
.content { float: left; margin-left: 206px; padding: 9px 12px;  overflow: hidden; }
.sidebar:after,
.clearfix:after { content: ''; display: table; clear: both; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; height: 0; }

/* Header CSS Styles */

.logo { width: 353px; float: left; margin: 28px 0 18px 6px; }
.logo img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }

.customer-nav ul { float: right; list-style: none; }
.customer-nav ul li { display: inline-block; margin-right: 12px; }
.customer-nav ul li a { font-family: "myriadpro_regular", sans-serif; font-size: 13px; color: #8e8e8e; text-decoration: none; }
.customer-nav ul li a:hover { color: #bebebe; }

.search:after,
.clearfix:after { content: ''; display: table; clear: both; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; height: 0; }
.search { position: relative; top: 63px; z-index: 2; }
.search-field { position: absolute; left: 75.6%; padding: 7px; background: #5a9abe; border-radius: 0; border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; }

.field { width: 221px; border: 0; border-top: 1px solid #7f7f7f; border-left: 1px solid #7f7f7f; border-radius: 3px; padding: 7px 10px 5px 35px; color: #a0a0a3; font-style: italic; }

.icon { position: relative; }
.icon-magnifier:after { content: ''; position: absolute; top: 0; left:8px; width: 12px; height: 16px; background: url(../images/magnifier.png) no-repeat 0 0; }
.shadow-line { width: 2px; position: absolute; top: 9px; left: 34px; }
.shadow-line img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }

.main-nav { min-width: 100%; height: 48px; position: relative; z-index: 999999; }
.main-nav {
 background: rgb(149,197,222);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(149,197,222,1) 0%, rgba(141,188,212,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(149,197,222,1) 0%,rgba(141,188,212,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(149,197,222,1) 0%,rgba(141,188,212,1) 100%);
}

.navigation { border-top: 7px solid #5a9abe; }
.navigation ul { list-style: none; margin: 9px 0 0 18px; }
.navigation ul li { display: inline-block; }
.navigation li a { font-family: "Bentham", serif; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; font-size: 15px; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; /* SOME PADDING */ }
.navigation ul li a:hover { color: #528bac; }
.navigation ul li + li:before { content: ''; border-right: 1px solid #74accb; margin: 0 15px 0 15px; }

/* Sidebar CSS Styles */

.widgeds { width: 200px; list-style: none; }

.widget h3 { font-family: "Bentham", serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; text-transform: uppercase; padding: 9px 12px 7px 12px; margin-bottom: 6px; }
.widget h3 {
 background: rgb(238,238,238);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%, rgba(222,222,222,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(222,222,222,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(222,222,222,1) 100%);
}
.widget { background: #fafafa; border: 1px solid #e2e2e2; margin-bottom: 6px; } 
.widget ul { list-style: none; padding-bottom: 2px; }
.widget ul li { margin-bottom: 1px; }
.widget ul li a { display: block; font-family: "myriadproregular", sans-serif; font-size: 14px; padding: 0px 11px 2px 12px; text-decoration: none; color: #3f3f3f; line-height: 25px; }
.widget ul li a:hover { color: #528bac; }

.product-image { display: block; width: 162px; border: 1px solid #bebebe; }
.product-image img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }
.product-image:hover { opacity: 0.8; }

.title { font-family: "myriadproregular", sans-serif; font-size: 14px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; }
.price { text-align: center; font-family: "myriadproregular", sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #528bac; padding: 0 4px 12px 4px; }

.btn { display: inline-block; padding: 3px 12px 1px 12px; color: #fff; border: 0; border-radius: 4px; border-bottom: 1px solid #336990; text-decoration: none; }
.btn-details { 
 background: rgb(99,157,197);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(99,157,197,1) 0%, rgba(61,125,171,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(99,157,197,1) 0%,rgba(61,125,171,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(99,157,197,1) 0%,rgba(61,125,171,1) 100%);
}

.view-featured { font-family: "myriadproregular", sans-serif; font-size: 12px; text-align: center; padding: 0 5px 7px 8px; }
.view-featured a { text-decoration: none; color: #3f3f3f; }
.view-featured a:hover { color: #528bac; }

/* Content CSS Styles */

.product-labels { font-family: "myriadproregular", sans-serif; }
.product-labels h1 { font-size: 12px; color: #528bac; text-transform: uppercase; padding-bottom: 2px; }
.product-labels p { float:left; font-size: 11px; color: #b2b2b2; padding-left: 2px; margin-bottom: 22px; letter-spacing: 0.03em; }

.product-list { text-align: justify; float: left; }
.item { text-align: center; }


.product-list ul { margin-right: -22px; }
.product-list ul li { list-style: none; float: left; width: 162px; margin: 0 26px 47px 0; }
.product-list ul li img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; border: 1px solid #b7b7b7; }
.product-list ul li a { color: #fff; }
.product-list ul li a:hover { opacity: 0.8; }

.footer { background: #5d9dc0; padding: 25px 0 23px 0; text-align: center; color: #fff; font-family: "Arial", sans-serif; font-size: 12px; border-top: 1px solid #e2e2e2; }
.footer { clear: both; }

::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #a0a0a3; font-style: italic; }
:-moz-placeholder { color: #a0a0a3; font-style: italic; }
::-moz-placeholder { color: #a0a0a3; font-style: italic; }
:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #a0a0a3; font-style: italic; }


@media (max-width: 959px) {
    .container { width: 768px; padding: 0 20px; }
    .footer { background: red; }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .container { width: 100%; padding: 0 15px; }
    .footer { background: green; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Bedding Store Template</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bentham" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <header class="header">
   <div class="logo">
    <img src="images/logo.png" width="353" height="46" title="someText" alt="someText">
   </div><!-- /.logo -->
   <nav class="customer-nav">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">View Cart</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Checkout</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav><!-- /.customer-nav -->
   <div class="search">
    <div class="search-field">
     <a href="#" class="icon icon-magnifier"></a>
     <img src="images/shadow-line.png" width="2" height="26" title="someText" alt="someText" class="shadow-line">
     <input type="search" name="search" id="search-input" placeholder="Search" class="field">
    </div><!-- /.search-field -->
   </div><!-- /.search-field -->
   <div class="main-nav">
    <nav class="navigation">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">new products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">specials</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">my account</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav><!-- /.nav -->
   </div><!-- /.main-nav -->
  </header><!-- /.header -->
  <main class="main">
   <aside class="sidebar">
    <ul class="widgeds">
     <li class="widget">
      <h3>Shop by categories</h3>

      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Comforters</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Sheets</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Qults &amp; Bed Covers</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Pillows &amp; Bedding Basics</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Bath Shop</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Gifts</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Clearance</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li><!-- /.widget -->

     <li class="widget">
      <h3>more information</h3>

      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Shipping Information</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Return Policy</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li><!-- /.widget -->
     
     <li class="widget">
      <h3>featured products</h3>
       <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="product-image"><img src="images/la-crosse-down-comforter.jpg" width="162" height="162" title="someText" alt="someText"></a>
        <p class="title">La Crosse&copy; Down Comforter</p>
        <!-- /.title -->
        <p class="price">&dollar;197.00</p><!-- /.price -->
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-details">Details</a>
       </div><!-- /.item -->
      <p class="view-featured"><a href="">View All Featured</a></p>
     </li><!-- /.widget -->
    </ul><!-- /.widgeds -->
   </aside><!-- /.sidebar -->
   
   <div class="content">
    <div class="product-labels">
     <h1>products > comforters</h1>
     <p>Displaying 1-12 of 12 Product(s)</p>
    </div><!-- /.products-label -->
    <div class="product-list">
     <ul>
      <li>
       <div class="item">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/white-bay-supersize.jpg" width="162" height="162" title="someText" alt="someText" class="product-example"></a>
        <p class="title">White Bay&copy; Supersize</p>
        <!-- /.title -->
        <p class="price">&dollar;339.00</p><!-- /.price -->
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-details">Details</a>
       </div><!-- /.item -->
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="item">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/supersize-baffled-square.jpg" width="162" height="162" title="someText" alt="someText" class="product-example"></a>
        <p class="title">Supersize Baffled Square</p>
        <!-- /.title -->
        <p class="price">&dollar;229.00</p><!-- /.price -->
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-details">Details</a>
       </div><!-- /.item -->
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="item">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/framework-tcs-down.jpg" width="162" height="162" title="someText" alt="someText" class="product-example"></a>
        <p class="title">Framework TCS&copy; Down</p>
        <!-- /.title -->
        <p class="price">&dollar;219.00</p><!-- /.price -->
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-details">Details</a>
       </div><!-- /.item -->
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="item">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/st-tropez-solid.jpg" width="162" height="162" title="someText" alt="someText" class="product-example"></a>
        <p class="title">St. Tropez&copy; Solid</p>
        <!-- /.title -->
        <p class="price">&dollar;114.00</p><!-- /.price -->
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-details">Details</a>
       </div><!-- /.item -->
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="product-image"><img src="images/legends-damask-baffled.jpg" width="162" height="162" title="someText" alt="someText"></a>
        <p class="title">Legends&copy; Damask Baffled</p>
        <!-- /.title -->
        <p class="price">&dollar;509.00</p><!-- /.price -->
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-details">Details</a>
       </div><!-- /.item -->
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="item">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/diamond-supersize.jpg" width="162" height="162" title="someText" alt="someText" class="product-example"></a>
        <p class="title">Diamond&copy; Supersize</p>
        <!-- /.title -->
        <p class="price">&dollar;259.00</p><!-- /.price -->
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-details">Details</a>
       </div><!-- /.item -->
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="item">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/la-crosse-supersize.jpg" width="162" height="162" title="someText" alt="someText" class="product-example"></a>
        <p class="title">La Crosse&copy; Supersize</p>
        <!-- /.title -->
        <p class="price">&dollar;143.00</p><!-- /.price -->
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-details">Details</a>
       </div><!-- /.item -->
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="item">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/white-bay-midsize.jpg" width="162" height="162" title="someText" alt="someText" class="product-example"></a>
        <p class="title">White Bay&copy; Midsize</p>
        <!-- /.title -->
        <p class="price">&dollar;319.00</p><!-- /.price -->
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-details">Details</a>
       </div><!-- /.item -->
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="item">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/st.tropez-stripe.jpg" width="162" height="162" title="someText" alt="someText" class="product-example"></a>
        <p class="title">St. Tropez&copy; Stripe</p>
        <!-- /.title -->
        <p class="price">&dollar;114.00</p><!-- /.price -->
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-details">Details</a>
       </div><!-- /.item -->
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="item">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/legends-imperial.jpg" width="162" height="162" title="someText" alt="someText" class="product-example"></a>
        <p class="title">Legends&copy; Imperial</p>
        <!-- /.title -->
        <p class="price">&dollar;820.00</p><!-- /.price -->
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-details">Details</a>
       </div><!-- /.item -->
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="item">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/baffled-supersize-square.jpg" width="162" height="162" title="someText" alt="someText" class="product-example"></a>
        <p class="title">Supersize Baffled Square</p>
        <!-- /.title -->
        <p class="price">&dollar;199.00</p><!-- /.price -->
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-details">Details</a>
       </div><!-- /.item -->
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="item">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/greek-key-supersize.jpg" width="162" height="162" title="someText" alt="someText" class="product-example"></a>
        <p class="title">Greek Key&trade; Supersize</p>
        <!-- /.title -->
        <p class="price">&dollar;159.00</p><!-- /.price -->
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-details">Details</a>
       </div><!-- /.item -->
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div><!-- /.gallery-container -->
   </div><!-- /.content -->
   <footer class="footer">
    <p> 2011, Bedding Store - All Rights Reserved. - CoreCommerce Ecommerce Software &amp; Shopping Cart Software</p>
   </footer><!-- /.footer -->
  </main><!-- /.main -->
 </div><!-- /.container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

add this css

```
.sidebar {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 6px 14px 0 6px;
    width: 206px;
}
.content {
    float: left;
    /*margin-left: 206px;*//*Remove this*/
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 9px 12px;
    width: calc(100% - 206px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

give each class **fixed width** and make them both float left . it will work